# Create new keys and secrets in Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create new keys/secrets and add them to the Azure Key Vault using the C# API. I can't really find any useful documentation or instructions on how to do this, I have been trying something like

```
keyVaultClient.SetSecretAsync("myKeyVaultUrl", "My test secret", "12345");
```

which doesn't seem to do anything, but that's about all I have.

For keys, I see that I can do

```
KeyBundle keyBundle = await keyVaultClient.CreateKeyAsync("myKeyVaultUrl", "My Test Key", "RSA");
```

but again, I don't know what to do with this key bundle.

Comment: Did you find exact practical difference between these two? If yes, help me with practical example.

Answer (score 1):

This sample application contains code that might help you on your journey:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45343

You can also manage Azure Key Vault with [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [Azure Cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-manage-with-cli), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started). Which is the recommended way, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

See the Microsoft example code here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-authentication

specifically, line 80 of KeyVaultAuthSample.cs creates a new Secret and pushes it to Azure: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-authentication/blob/master/KeyVaultAuthSample.cs#L80

To push a key bundle up to Azure, look at the method KeyVaultClient.ImportKeyAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.importkeyasync

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI to create it like this:

az keyvault secret set --vault-name (vaultName) --name (Secretname) --value (actualvalue)

Eg: az keyvault secret set --vault-name "MyVault" --name "FBPassword" --value "123"

Check here for more information:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/cli-samples

In codes here is the method signature:

```
public static Task<SecretBundle> SetSecretAsync(this IKeyVaultClient operations, string vaultBaseUrl, string secretName, string value, IDictionary<string, string> tags = null, string contentType = null, SecretAttributes secretAttributes = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

In codes you can: 
first set these then

```
contentType = null; 
SecretAttributes secretAttributes = null;
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;

SecretBundle secretBundle = await _keyVaultClient.SetSecretAsync(("myKeyVaultUrl", "My test secret", "12345", null, null, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

`VaultClient.ImportKeyAsync` creates a new key in the specified Key-Vault.

```
    public static void Import()
    {
        KeyVaultClient vaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(GetAccessToken);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

        var keyBundle = Task.Run(() => vaultClient.ImportKeyAsync("<YOUR BASE VAULT ID>", "ImportedKey", new KeyBundle(new JsonWebKey(rsaProvider, true)), true)).
           ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }

    public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        string AppId = "<YOUR APP ID GUID>";
        string AppSecret = "<YOUR APP SECRET>";

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(AppId, AppSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

        if (result == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

[image]